# Unable to move my linear gradient to the bottom of my image

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am very new to web development and I have come across an obstacle.

I want to have the linear gradient at the bottom of the image (so the image fades into black) however I'm not sure on how to bring it there. Would I need to change the size of the background image or the gradient, I'm not too sure. I will attach my css and an image.

Any help would be appreciated!  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds14R.jpg)

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}
body{
    background-color:black;
    min-height:3000px;
    min-width:0px;
    background-image:url("images/background.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    
}
#section{
    object-fit:cover;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:none;
    pointer-events:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;


    
}

section:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 80%, #000 100%);
    z-index: 100000;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply it directly to your body's background image.

```
 body {
    background-color:black;
    min-height:3000px;
    min-width:0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0%), rgba(0, 0, 0, 100%)), url("images/background.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! It appears that if i wanted to increase the "min-height" to lets say 6000px; the linear gradient doesn't have the same effect. What should I do? (I would like to be able to scroll down.)

Comment: What do you mean? It will still be black at the bottom and transparent at the top

Comment: When I set the min-height to 6000px the transition between the black and the image isn't as smooth as 2000px. I would like to get the same result as 2000px but on 6000px with the added bonus of being able to scroll further.

Comment: I might be missing your point but it seems like you want to have 2 opposite things at the same time :D

Comment: Maybe just make gradient on image and then just use black color as a background for the rest of the page.

Comment: Ahh okayyy gotcha! Thank you very much for your patience and help - I really appreciate it!